# For polynomials the definition of differentiation can be given purely algebraically and does not require the usual theory of limiting processes.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I was doing a question to show that the differentiation operator on a polynomial of degree n is a linear transformation, ending with a note stated as above. i did not understand the note. what is the theory of limiting process?

Comment: The limiting process is the usual modern definition of differentiation, as stated in a calculus course.

Comment: One way to do it is to define $f'$ formally for elements $f$ in the polynomial ring $\mathbb R[x]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be any commutative ring; consider the polynomial ring in two variables $A[x,E]$ and, for any polynomial $f(x)\in A[x]$, the two-variable polynomial
$$
\hat{f}(x,E)=f(x+E)-f(x)
$$
Since $\hat{f}(x,0)=0$, we have that $E$ divides $\hat{f}(x,E)$ and therefore we can consider
$$
\tilde{f}(x,E)=\frac{\hat{f}(x,E)}{E}\in A[x,E]
$$
Now define
$$
f'(x)=\tilde{f}(x,0)\in A[x]
$$
and prove the basic facts about derivatives:
$$
(f(x)+g(x))'=f'(x)+g'(x),
\qquad
(f(x)g(x))'=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)
$$

This is basically what Fermat did for his derivatives, when dealing with polynomials.